# MS Excel - VLOOKUP result is not calculated automatically

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have an application that generates a file that include VLOOKUP formulas, but the result is not calculated automatically. I need to manually press F2 + Enter to have the result calculated.

Facts:

- I already set: Formulas > Calculation Options > Automatic
- B6:B17 and B19:B26 have the "General" format
- B28:30 and B32:34 have the "Numeric" format

**The final idea is to print the text only, not the number zero**

Here is a copy from the file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ai_bHPXqfyZSQeSfUN8XcEIJz4fX7gqh?usp=sharing

Comment: There's no info in Settings cells B2:B12. If I enter info in that page, vlookup formula returns data automatically. Maybe it's something related to your excel instance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem used to happen when I was to export a table or data directly from `SAP` to `Excel`.

To tackle this issue, in the `Summary Page` select whole `Column B` and then go to `Data > Text to Columns > Finish`.

It will be solved.

Comment: It worked, but this is something I need to do everytime the report is generated? Because the app that generates the file is based on a template.

Comment: Tested with the application, it does not do what I expected. Anytime the file is generated, the values are still empty. They are filled after going to the text to columns option. I expect to print automatically the values right after the file is opened.

Comment: Then I think you need to contact the app developers that created it.. Only they can do something about it.